# SQ Server : how to find the fifth order for each customer

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

How to find the fifth order for each customer and return `title_order` or null if the customer doesn't have the fifth order

Tables are

- `customer` with columns `Id, firstname, lastname`...
- `order` with columns `order_id,  title_order, id_custmer, date`...

It can be done only with a query or do I need to create a function

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Fifth order* - **ordered by what**? You need to define what you want your orders to be ordered by, in order to count to the fifth order.....

Comment: sorry order by date, the result that I want is first_name of customer and next fild returns the Title_order if the customer has the fifth order, thanks :), I have an answer below but can we do this in another way without using OUTER APPLY with OFFSET-FETCH, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` with `OFFSET-FETCH`:

```
select c.firstname, oa.title_order 
from customer c
outer apply(select title_order from order o 
            where o.id_custmer = c.Id 
            order by date 
            offset 4 ROW FETCH next 1 ROW only)oa
```

Comment: the result that I want is first_name of customer and next fild returns the Title_order if the customer has the fifth order, if not returns null   thanks for answering

Comment: thanks it works :) , I didn't know the command that you apply

Comment: sorry again @Giorgi, is thene any way to solve this with function because I'm studing functions, I'm trying but I have not solve it yet (with function), thanks